# Retornar true quando variável BigDecimal for diferente de nulo, caso contrário retornar false

Tags: operadores, kotlin, booleano

- Possuo um atributo do tipo `BigDecimal` x.
- Preciso chamar um método `exampleMethod()`.
- Gostaria de passar por parâmetro `true` ou `false` dependendo se o x é nulo ou não, como no exemplo abaixo:

  ```
  val x: BigDecimal? = null 

  if (x != null)
      exampleMethod(true)
  else
      exampleMethod(false)
  ```

Existe uma outra forma mais otimizada de verificar se é nulo e que retorne `true` ou `false` pra que eu não precise utilizar o `if`? Como no exemplo em Java abaixo:

```
exampleMethod(Objects.nonNull(x))
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2):

Garantidamente mais otimizada não tem, mas mais curta tem:

```
exampleMethod(x != null)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/NonNull.kt).

Uma expressão que tenha um operador relacional sempre resulta em um valor booleano, portanto `true` se aquela comparação é verdadeira e `false` se não for, e esses valores são exatamente o que você quer usar como argumento na chamada do método, então não tem porque dar voltas, use de forma direta o valor que a expressão resulta.

A forma do Java deve funcionar também se fizer a importação do pacote corretamente, mas acho bem desnecessário porque internamente ele fará a comparação que eu indiquei. Mudo de ideia se alguém me mostrar porque essa abstração traz alguma vantagem. Só não funciona se usar Kotlin fora da JVM ou assemelhado ([tem no Android também](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Objects#nonNull(java.lang.Object))), conforme comentário abaixo, e isso seria mais um motivo para não usar algo dependente dela.

Comment: Para completar a respostas do Maniero, se você estiver rodando Kotlin na JVM pode usar a API do Java sem problemas. O seu próprio exemplo de código é válido em Kotlin: `exampleMethod(Objects.nonNull(x))`. Dependendo da situação há também opções idiomáticas como o *Elvis Operator*; para mais informações dê uma olhada na documentação oficial sobre [*Null Safety*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Comment: Obrigado aos dois. o/

Comment: Maniero, *off-topic*, mas respondendo ao seu *update*. Nesse caso não há vantagem alguma de usar `Objects.nonNull` mesmo. Esse método foi introduzido no Java 8 e pode ser utilizado como alternativa idiomática para *lambdas* quando um *predicate* é esperado. E.g., `stream.filter(Objects::nonNull)` como alternativa a `stream.filter(elem -> elem != null)`